# How to find out first author of a code in perforce

Tags: perforce

There is a c file in a source code repository(maintained by perforce) I am working on. Many people have made changes over time in that file. There is a while loop written inside that file. I want to know the author who has first introduced this while loop. If I use p4annotate then it is showing me some author who first removed this loop and later again added that loop. I mean he is not the first author of that while loop. Is there any way to know first author of that piece of code?

Comment: Use the `-a` flag to `p4 annotate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options to `p4 annotate` that might be useful:

- `p4 annotate file#REV` starts the annotation at an earlier revision, so you could go back to the revision before the loop was deleted and see who'd last added it as of that revision.
- `p4 annotate -a file` shows all of the lines of the file, including those that have been deleted, so you'll see the original version of the while loop.
- `p4 annotate -I file` traces the origin of individual lines through merge operations from other files.

All of these options can be combined, so you can do things like `p4 annotate -a -I file#START,#END` to get detailed information (including merge sources) about all the lines added to the file between two points in time.